# How can I shred socket object over python multiProcess? It raises EOFError

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing

I am trying to test `multiProcess Procee` Class with simple code.

But When I hand over `socket` object as a parameter on Process, It raises `EOFError`.

Below is the simple Code and the Exception.

```
import multiprocessing
import socket

class Multi(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, s):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.s = s

    def run(self):
        for i in range(100):
            print "aaaa"


if __name__ in "__main__":
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    p = Multi(s)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sangmin\workspace\multiProcessTest\multiProcessTest.py", line 24, in <module>
    p.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 277, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 199, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <built-in method recvfrom_into of _socket.socket object at 0x020C94A0>: it's not found as __main__.recvfrom_into
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, `multiprocessing` uses pickle to transfer objects between processes. Socket objects can not be pickled, hence the problem that you see.

Your code does work in Linux, and that is because `multiprocessing` uses `fork` on that platform. The child of a forked process inherits the parent's file handles, of which one is the socket.

It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. You could communicate the hostname and port information to the sub process, and have it create its own socket.

You should also be able to get it to work with `threading` instead of `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Actually my intention is to use `socket` as substitute of `pipe` with `select` because only `socket` is available for `select`  in `windows`. so in my real code I was trying to hand over socket dictionary like `{"read" : socket1, "write" : socket2}`

Comment: You could use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue). The `put` and `get` methods are blocking with timeouts and so could provide select like behaviour.